# Equivalent for ULONG64 datatype in Visual Studio 2005/2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Currently I facing a problem related to ULONG64 datatype...I was going through some code possibly compiled in some other VC++ compiler. There, there is a datatype defined as ULONG64. When I try to use the same data type in Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 I get the following error:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Kindly tell me why is this happening and how to rectify this error. Is there any equivalent data type in VS2005/2008 for ULONG64.

Thanks,
Mr. Elusive

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` make things back to work.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with my compiler but it states - cannot include file <windows.h> - No such file or directory. I am using VS2005 Express Edition.

Comment: Well then, so why don't you download Windows SDK and get the missing headers and libraries. Windows SDK http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3138 will support VS 2008 only though, you would need to look for older versions to make them work with VS 2005.

Comment: Thanks @RomanR. There were indeed some headers and libraries missing from my system. Re-installing the product and then using `#include <windows.h>` served the purpose.